# An INSERT statement triggers the SQL Server Audit to write it down in the logs although INSERT is not listed as an Audit Action

Tags: sql-server, audit, sql-server-2019, logs

**Background:**
I am trying to keep a track record of what users are querying in the database. One option I found is to create a Server and Database Audit Specification. I did not want to include INSERT statements since those are going to be logged for each record inserted which will be a lot if there are bulks of data being added to the table(s).

**Problem:**
We have a SQL Job (within the Job Agent) that inserts data into a table using an INSERT query. I would expect these logs would not appear in our .sqlaudit file but it does. Even do INSERT is not apart of our Actions within our Database Audit Specifications. I am wondering if it is triggered do to another action? I have listed all the actions that I have included but from my understanding none of them will trigger the server to write the INSERT logs in the .sqlaudit file. What could be the issue?

***NOTE:*** I have also executed an INSERT query using the query tool and it still logs that as well.

**Audit Action Types Added to Database Audit Specifications:**

- DATABASE_OBJECT_ACCESS_GROUP
- SCHEMA_OBJECT_ACCESS_GROUP
- DATABASE_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP
- SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP
- DELETE
- EXECUTE
- SELECT
- UPDATE

Here is the statement that it is logging in the .sqlaudit file:

```
INSERT [dbo].[table_name]([a],[b],[c],[d],[e],[f],[g],[h],[i],[j],[k],[l]) VALUES(@Param000004,@Param000005,@Param000006,@Param000007,@Param000008,@Param000009,@Param000010,@Param000011,@Param000012,@Param000013,@Param000014,@Param000015)
```

Comment: Is there any trigger configured on that table? When you run an INSERT outside of that job, is it also captured by the audit?

Comment: Is this insert part of a procedure? Do you EXECUTE it?

Comment: @Ronaldo Yes, when I run the INSERT statement outside the job. It still logs the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal approach would be to disable the `INSERT` audit for that table, but since you seem to have a peculiar situation, here's one way of dealing with it:

Once you made sure the `INSERT` audit is not enabled by connecting to the audited database and running [this query](https://gist.github.com/nullbind/5da8b5113da007ba0111):

```
-- List enabled database specifications
SELECT  a.audit_id,
        a.name as audit_name,
        s.name as database_specification_name,
        d.audit_action_name,
        s.is_state_enabled,
        d.is_group,
        s.create_date,
        s.modify_date,
        d.audited_result
FROM sys.server_audits AS a
JOIN sys.database_audit_specifications AS s
ON a.audit_guid = s.audit_guid
JOIN sys.database_audit_specification_details AS d
ON s.database_specification_id = d.database_specification_id
WHERE s.is_state_enabled = 1
```

You can filter that audit to avoid the inserts from being registered. The [Create a Server Audit and Server Audit Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-server-audit-specification?view=sql-server-ver15) doc says:

> 3. Optionally, on the Filter page, enter a predicate, or WHERE clause,
>    to the server audit to specify additional options not available from
>    the General page. Enclose the predicate in parentheses; for example:
>    (object_name = 'EmployeesTable').

The Filter page can be found by `right click the audit > properties`. If you prefer, the T-SQL to alter the audit not to register the inserts would be something like this:

```
USE [master]
GO

ALTER SERVER AUDIT [Your_Audit_Name]
WHERE (NOT [statement] LIKE 'INSERT%')
GO
```

---

**Some relevant content:**

[Filter SQL Server Audit on action_id / class_type predicate](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/filter-sql-server-audit-on-action-id-class-type-predicate/ba-p/384140)

[sys.fn_get_audit_file (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

[How to analyze and read SQL Server Audit information](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/analyze-and-read-sql-server-audit-information/)