# Getting database-level audit logs without database audit specification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, audit

I have server level auditing on SQL Server 2014.
Why am I receiving database-level audit events (such as SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc.), even though there are no database audit specifications?

I see these, for example running the following command:

```
SELECT *
FROM fn_get_audit_file('\Audit\*', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
WHERE [action_id] = 'SL'
```

But I have not specified database auditing. The following commands come back with no results:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_audit_specifications
SELECT * FROM sys.database_audit_specification_details
```

It's on Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Standard (SP1-GDR) - 12.0.4237.0

Comment: Please, see if [An INSERT statement triggers the SQL Server Audit to write it down in the logs although INSERT is not listed as an Audit Action](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/286926/an-insert-statement-triggers-the-sql-server-audit-to-write-it-down-in-the-logs-a/287218#287218) is of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably defined the SCHEMA_OBJECT_ACCESS_GROUP for the server audit.

You *can* capture database level events at the server level, like above. This will then be applied for all databases. Above captures all SELECT etc on all tables and views on the entire instance.

This explains why you see SELECT events without having a database audit specification.