# Logging commands run by a user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

As I am slightly new to SQL Server administration I am struggling with a requirement given to me by my security audit team. We have a web based application which is using MS SQL Server 2017 as database server. The users of the application are being authenticated through LDAP hence no SQL server logins/ database users have been separately created. However, there are two admin logins  which are responsible for maintaining the database. The audit team has asked to record all the commands/queries which are run directly on server by SQL admin logins. I have tried capturing those with SQL Server Audit, but it is capturing way lot more of information than what is actually required. Is there any other better way of doing this or SQL Server Audit is the only solution.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here, but there are several third-party auditing tools that might do what you want. If you rephrase your question to be more about how to effectively filter out the information that doesn't match your auditing needs, you might get some helpful answers. Maybe include some examples of the audit log entries that you want to see, and examples of the entries that you don't want to see.

Comment: Why don't you create a filter for that audit to reduce what's being captured? see if [this answer related to filtering the audit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/286926/an-insert-statement-triggers-the-sql-server-audit-to-write-it-down-in-the-logs-a/287218#287218) helps.